# Mostrar por consola un Array

Tags: c#, enum

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace Ejercicio3
     {
     class Program
     {
       enum direcion { arriba = 1, abajo = 3, derecha = 2, izquieda = 4, 
       abajoDerecha=23, abajoIzquierda=34,arribaDerecha=12,
       arribaIzquieda=14, prohibido };
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          string num = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Escribe la direcion que desees tomar");
        num = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] array = num.Split(',');

        direcion d = (direcion)Int32.Parse(num);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", (direcion)int.Parse(num.Substring(i, 1)));
        }

    }
}
}
```

Quiero separar lo que escriba por consola por `','` he buscado y se hace con el metodo `Split` pero de esa manera lo cambia a `array`.

Lo que no sé es como mostrar ahora este `array`.

Es decir quiero que me muestre los `enums` si yo introduzco `1,2,3,4 etc`. Entendí como hacerlo mostrado por un `string` pero no se con un `array`.

CREO que me falla esto;

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", (direcion)int.Parse(num.Substring(i, 1)));
```

Esta linea como vengo de java no la entiendo muy bien.
Y ya si se trata de subir el nivel y hacerlo con `arrays` aun menos...

Si podéis explicarme como hacerlo ademas de aclararme esta linea que no entiendo os lo agradecería.

Comment: A ver, lo primero debes quitar lo de `direcion d = (direcion)Int32.Parse(num);` ya que no sirve para nada y probablemente debería lanzar una excepción. Para mostrar el array, es igual que en java: `Console.WriteLine("{0}", (direcion)int.Parse(array[i]));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las buenas practicas de C# recomiendan usar foreach en vez de for, en caso que no se modifique las variables y precises iterar por todo el array ((http://blog.submain.com/c-array):

> Best Practice #4: Use the for loop if you need to iterate over a portion of an array or you need to change the elements of the array in some fashion as you iterate. Use foreach when you don’t want to change anything in the array and you need to iterate through all elements.).

En la siguiente url te dejó como quedaría tu código:
https://rextester.com/WOTPRL56515

Código:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
       enum direcion { arriba = 1, abajo = 3, derecha = 2, izquieda = 4, 
       abajoDerecha=23, abajoIzquierda=34,arribaDerecha=12,
       arribaIzquieda=14, prohibido };
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string num = "";
            Console.WriteLine("Escribe la direcion que desees tomar");
            num = "1,2,3,4";
            string[] array = num.Split(',');

            Array.ForEach(array, (item) => {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", (direcion)int.Parse(item));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Lo primero que estabas haciendo mal era trabajar en el for con num, debería ser con array[i], luego la variable "d" es declarada pero no usada.

Comment: Puedes especificar donde están las buenas practicas donde se recomienda usar funciones lambda en vez de for? Por otro lado, podrías [edit] tu respuesta para añadir el código? El enlace donde está actualmente posiblemente desaparezca en un tiempo, dejando tu respuesta incompleta. Y por último, el OP no estaba trabajando con `num` en el `for`...

Comment: Encuanto a las buenas practicas (https://blog.submain.com/c-array/): "Best Practice #4: Use the for loop if you need to iterate over a portion of an array or you need to change the elements of the array in some fashion as you iterate. Use foreach when you don’t want to change anything in the array and you need to iterate through all elements." En cuanto a lo último: `for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", (direcion)int.Parse(num.Substring(i, 1)));
        }`

Comment: En el codigo que citas no menciona funciones lambda, habla de for y foreach, esta de mas el comentario de buenas practicas